# Not able to get python stdout logs in container to "oc logs"

Tags: python, cron, containers, openshift, stdout

I have an openshift container running a cron job. This cron job runs some python code.
I have set up a logger to stream the logs to stdout and I expect to see these logs when I query "oc logs [pod] -c [container]", but I don't.

This is the defined logger:

```
import os
import logging.config

synthetic_home = os.environ.get('SYNTHETIC_HOME')
logPath = '{0}/logs/'.format(synthetic_home)
fileName = 'synthetic.log'

synthetic_log_name = os.environ.get('LOG_NAME')
if not synthetic_log_name:
    synthetic_log_name = 'synthetic-onlinevideoservices'


config = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    },

    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s, {0}, SYNTH_TEST, %(levelname)s, FCID=%(fcid)s, *%(test_name)s* %(message)s'.format(synthetic_log_name),
            #            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '{0}/{1}'.format(logPath, fileName),
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'stream': {
                'level': 'INFO',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'standard'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'results': {
            'handlers': ['stream'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True

        }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

I am not sure if the fact that this code runs from a cron job is important or not here.
In any case, I need the INFO logs to be reflected in "oc logs" and they are not.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere where you're specifying `sys.stdout` as the stream for your `StreamHandler`. The default stream for a `StreamHandler` is `None`.

Comment: There's an example in https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details that shows `stream  : ext://sys.stdout`

Comment: Thanks @WillGordon - giving it a try now

Comment: still doesn't work. The stream logger now looks like this:
`'stream': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filters': ['fcid_filter', 'test_name_filter'],
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
        }`

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, why not try `'stream': { 'level': 'DEBUG', 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', 'formatter': 'standard', 'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout' }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a conda environment? If yes, you need to have these `--no-capture-output` AND `--live-streaming` flags in your entry point command.